# changing specific letters in a Turkish text with R

Tags: r

I am analyzing a Turkish text. I need to change some letters in the text. Since in Turkish there are ş ç ı ğ ü ö letters. I want to change them with s c i g u o. How can I handle it?

I have used following for the one letter, but it did not work, nothing changed in the text. 
gsub("s","ş" , text)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `chartr`. Example

```
> string <- "ş ç ı ğ ü ö f s x q"
> chartr("ş ç ı ğ ü ö", "s c i g u o", string)
[1] "s c i g u o f s x q"
```

Another alternative is `stri_trans_general` from stringi package

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_trans_general(string, "latin-ascii")
[1] "s c i g u o f s x q"
```